# How can I disable SharePoint 2010 ULS Log Entry Truncation?

Tags: sharepoint, logging, sharepoint-2010, uls

When using code to write an entry to the SharePoint 2010 ULS Log, I have found that they are limited to a length of 95,999 characters. I have found no documentation online specifying this limit, nor have I found any way of changing this limit. I need to log large serialized objects for diagnostic purposes - **how can I log entries longer than 95,999 characters to the ULS log?**

This is the code I've used to verify the maximum length allowed:

```
private void Run()
{
    var logger = SPDiagnosticsService.Local;
    logger.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("TestLogLimits", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error),
        TraceSeverity.High,
        GetLongMessage(length: 96000), null); //Last character is truncated - only 95,999 characters are stored 
}

private string GetLongMessage(int length)
{
    return new string('X', length);
}
```

**UPDATE 01:** In the log file itself, the entries are stored as 120 lines, 800 characters each - 120 x 800 = 96,000, which seems to be the limit. Still not sure what to do with this new information.

Answer (score 0):

Log it somewhere else.  ULS wasn't made for this type of info.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation that says so, by chance? Or at least, where it says what the limit is?

Comment: No.  It's just common sense.

Comment: Would you care to explain?

Comment: 96K per entry would be a royal PITA to read out of the ULS with the way it is formatted.  Writing your own logging component that can structure the data better would be trivial.  You likely could have done it already with the time you've spent trying to force the ULS logs to do what you need.

Comment: It's actually not a problem if you use a tool like ULSViewer. ULSViewer aggregates the lines (all 120 of them) into one entry for easy viewing. I wouldn't recommend that anyone parse the ULS Log files with a text editor.

Comment: Even with ULS Viewer(which I use) there are better formats for viewing large text entries.  Just because you **can** log 96K at a time  to the ULS, doesn't mean that you **should**

Comment: We can agree that viewing large bits of data would be problematic. It just occurred to me from your comment that WRITING 96K to the ULS log at a time could be an issue since the ULS log SEEMS to be built for smaller entries (I haven't seen any documentation on this, though). That being said, the data I'd like to log is not casually logged; rather, it's only logged for extreme exceptions, and even then ONLY when the administrator says it is ok to log it.